# Elements appearing in divs that they shouldn't be: HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a landing section in my HTML and I have icons below the landing. I can't figure out why the icons keep appearing in my landing div. I've checked for unclosed tags numerous times. I think I need another pair of eyes. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Fitness Food Tracker</title>

      <script src="vendor.bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
      <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="brand" alt="Brand" src="assets/styles/apple.png"></a>
          </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">account_circle</i> <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#" id="nav-sign-up">Sign Up</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" id="nav-sign-in">Sign In</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden" id="nav-li-user-stats"><a href="#" id="nav-user-stats">Update User Stats</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden" id="nav-li-sign-out"><a href="#" id="nav-sign-out">Sign Out</a></li>
                  <li class="hidden" id="nav-li-change-password"><a href="#" id="nav-change-password">Change Password</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>


        <div class='landing'>
          <!--- Sign Up Form ---->
          <form class="form-horizontal hidden" id=sign-up-form>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="credentials[email]" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="credentials[password]" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" name="credentials[password_confirmation]" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password Confirmation">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>
          <!-- Update User -->
          <form id='update-user-form' class='hidden'>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="weight-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Weight</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="weight-input" name="user[weight]" placeholder="Enter Your Weight">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="height-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Height</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="height-input" name="user[height]" placeholder="Enter Your Height">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="age-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Age</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="age-input"  name="user[age]" placeholder="Enter Your Age">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="gender-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Gender</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="gender-input" name="user[gender]" placeholder="Enter Your Gender (m or f)">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="activity-input" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Activity Level</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="activity-input" name="user[activity_level]" placeholder="Enter Acitivty Multiplier">
              </div>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary auth-form-element">
              Submit Your Info
            </button>

          </form>
          <!-- Sign In form -->
          <form class="form-horizontal hidden" id=sign-in-form>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="credentials[email]" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="credentials[password]" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign In</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </form>

          <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="container">
              <h1 class='landing-header'>Fitness Food Tracker</h1>
              <h3>An App For Tracking Your Calories and Maintaining Your Physique.</h3>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>






        <!---Below Landing --->

        <!-- Food Search-->
        <div class="col-md-6 search-input hidden">
          <label>Search For Food</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id='search-input-field' class="form-control" placeholder="Search for foods">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" id='food-search-btn' type="button">Search!</button>
            </span>
          </div><!-- /input-group -->
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->

        <!-- Meal Builder Display-->
          <div id="meal-content" class='hidden'>

            <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#red" data-toggle="tab">Search Results</a></li>
                <li><a href="#orange" data-toggle="tab">Your Meal</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="red">
                  <div class="search-table table-responsive table-bordered hidden">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="orange">
                  <div class="meal-table table-responsive table-bordered hidden">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                      <tr>
                        <th class='hidden'>id</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Calories</th>
                        <th>Grams Per Serving</th>
                        <th>Fat Mono</th>
                        <th>Fat Poly</th>
                        <th>Fat Sat</th>
                        <th>Carbs</th>
                        <th>Sugar</th>
                        <th>Fiber</th>
                        <th>Protien</th>
                        <th>Sodium</th>
                        <th>Cholesteral</th>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <label> Meal Macro Totals</label>
                  <div class="meal-total-table table-responsive table-bordered hidden">
                    <table class="table table-condensed">
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

          <div class='col-md-4 icon-div'>
            <i class="material-icons icon">create</i><br>
            Log Your Meals
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-4 icon-div'>
            <i class="material-icons icon">fitness_center</i><br>
              Maintain Your Fitness
          </div>
          <div class='col-md-4 icon-div'>
            <i class="material-icons icon">track_changes</i><br>
            Track Changes Over Time
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Photo of how it is currently appearing]

EDIT:

Here is my CSS:

```
$icon-font-path: '~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/';
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';

$orange: #EB8921;
$lite-orange: #F5AD28;
$white: #FFFFFF;
$gray: #2E2F2F;
$darker-gray: #1E1E1E;
$black: #000000;

body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  background-color:  $gray;
  color: $lite-orange;
};

.landing {
  background-image: url("http://wallpapercave.com/wp/EnDM8YS.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  height: 600px;
}

form {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#meal-content {
  margin-top: 8%;
}

.landing-header {
  color: $orange;
}

.icon-div {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: $gray;
}

.icon {
  padding-top: 10%;
  font-size: 8em;
  color: $white;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.jumbotron {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: .25px 0 0 $black, -.25px 0 0 $black, 0 .25px 0 $black, 0 -.25px 0 $black, .25px .25px $black;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.btn-primary {
  background: $orange;
  border-color: $black;
}

.table-responsive {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: .75em;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  background-color: $darker-gray;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.input-group-sm {
  min-width: 50px;
}

.search-input {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  float: none;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.add-food-btn {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.table {
  border: $black;
}

.a.dropdown-toggle {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.brand {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5%;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question. You left out at a minimum the relevant CSS

Comment: ok, I'll post the css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the icons end up behind the navbar because the navbar is fixed. Simply adding `padding-top` to the body should create some whitespace under the navbar and fix your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to get the icons to show up below the photo as well... I've been messing with it for a while, and can't figure out why its out of order. It should be nav>photo>icons and sometimes there will be content between the icons and photo when its not hidden

Comment: It's hard to write code on a phone, should be home soon. If no one else has helped you already I will.

Comment: @Atache It is because the `.landing` has `position: absolute`. [MDN CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). "Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor if any, or otherwise relative to the containing block.". Meaning that the element does not take up any space and is placed on top of any other element. Remove `position: absolute` from `.landing` and it should work. I can't test it myself unfortunately.